# Does defining 'static const variable in a struct' explicitly makes any difference in C++ 11 and above?

Tags: c++

I understood that in the older versions of C++, assigning a value to `const static variable` in a struct and not defining it outside the struct will not create a memory allocation for the variable, but will replace the `const static variable` with its assigned value during compilation and accessing the address of such a variable gives error (as the variable is not defined/allocated memory)

```
struct A{
    int i;
    static const int j = 20;
}
```

So, here to define the variable,this should be done to access it with address

```
const int A::j; //line1
```

But, in later versions of C++, even though the variable is not defined as in `line1`, memory is getting allocated and its address could be fetched.

I'm not sure whether adding `line1` in the versions from C++ 11 will make any difference in any other aspect (as memory is getting allocated without this line too). If it makes a difference, what would it be? (Is it just to provide backward compatability?)

Please help!!!

***Edit : I'm not sure whether such thing is accepted even before C++ 11, but since I observed it from C++ 11, I mentioned it (using MSVC++ 14.0)***

***Update : Also observed, when tried to print address of j without `line1`, In `MSVC++ 14.0`, it could print the address but with `gcc compiler (cpp.sh)`, it couldn't and it gives a link error `(undefined reference)`.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, inline variables will be introduced. A `static constexpr` data member of a class will be implicitly inline and will be a definition of that data member. Multiple definitions will be resolved at link time into a single address for that data member.

In your example, `A::j` is `const` but not `constexpr`, so that provision will not apply to it. Your example will work the same in all versions from C++98 to C++17.

In the case where `j` is `constexpr`, in C++17 and later, the out-of-line definition `const int A::j` will become a redundant declaration that the compiler will ignore. Yes, this is for backward compatibility reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my ques Brian :-)
Just now I observed that, when I tried to print address of `j` without `line1`, In `MSVC++ 14.0`, I could print the address but with `gcc` compiler (cpp.sh), I couldn't and it gives a link error (`undefined reference`). Till now I thought it is something to do with C++ version/standard, but the behaviour changes with compiler. Can you please help me!!!

Comment: @infiniteloop I believe this is a non-standard feature in Visual C++.

Comment: Yeah might be, Brian. In case you found anything new about this, kindly update. :-)

Comment: @infiniteloop It is an error to print the address of `j` without defining it. If a compiler lets you do that, its not standard C++

Comment: @PasserBy -- the compiler can "let you do that" if it issues a diagnostic. The C++ standard requires a diagnostic; it does not require compilers to refuse to compile non-conforming code. (I'm not saying that the compiler here issues a diagnostic, just clarifying what the standard actually requires)